# Python "match" statement is underlined red in PyCharm 2020.3.5, but "match" statement Works

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, switch-statement

I've installed Python 3.12 and tested the match statement successfully.
However, in PyCharm version 2020.3.5 Community Edition, 'match' and 'case' keywords are marked with red underlines
match statement works but match and case keywords are marked with red underlines

[image: screenshot of edit red underlines]

Why is PyCharm showing as such?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "match/case" is a new feature in Python 3.10, released in October 2021. Syntax highlighting code updated prior to this date (in this case more than one year earlier) could not know about it. The Python version you use is not bound to Pycharm version, and if match/case works it is 3.10 or newer.

Answer (score 2):

General support for `match`-`case` statements were added to PyCharm 2021.2 at the earliest, according to [this YouTrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-47446/Support-new-match-and-case-statements-PEP-634-635-636#focus=Comments-27-5451700.0-0).

That said, you need to update PyCharm. As of writing, the latest version is 2023.3.2, which has support for, among others, [the new type parameter syntax](https://peps.python.org/pep-0695/) introduced in Python 3.12.